# Let G be a simple, connected and planar graph which is not a tree.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, trees

Let G be a simple, connected and planar graph which is not a tree. Then it must have at least one cycle. Let the number of regions of G be f. We delete an edge a of a cycle in G to obtain the simple, connected and planar graph G − a.

What is the number of regions of G − a ?

Comment: Previously there was a region on the one side of the edge and a different region on the other side of the edge.  Those two regions used to be distinct (*be sure to be able to answer why*).  Now that the edge has been deleted, those two regions are now combined to be the same region (*be sure to be able to answer why*).  No other regions were affected (*be sure to be able to answer why*).  So, the total number of regions has decreased by one and is $f-1$.

Comment: According to Euler's theorem, a simple planar graph having n vertices and e edges determines f=e-n+2 regions. Now if we delete an edge 'a' of a cycle in the graph to obtain the simple, connected, and planar graph G-a, it will have f-1 regions.@JMoravitz

Comment: Is it correct @JMoravitz

Comment: @JMoravitz Not so sure to answer the 'why' question